# Electrical Fast transient generator

Tags: emc, signal-generator

I am trying to build my own EFT generator (IEC 610000-4-4). A person online had done some design and they have calculated the values of the components in order to make the circuit. I used LTSpice to simulate their component values and see what results I get. I am not using a switch as required by the standard for now, I just want to simulate one pulse.

[image]

What is wrong with my circuit?  How come I see such a low value at the output?

Comment: Did you mean to have a switch between the DC source and the pulse output? If this is for practical purposes, mind that you will need quite an excellent switch to do this.

Comment: Yes indeed, 
I agree 100% with you the topology of the switch will have to be very good, but for now I just want to start with that :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The voltage at the output is low because you've got a DC voltage and a capacitor, which blocks DC, in series with the output.

You will only see a significant voltage there when the input voltage changes.

You could change the voltage source to a pulse, then you would see an output.

Here I've changed it to a pulse, changed the simulation settings and added a couple of options to get better accuracy.
[image]

Comment: what are the parameters that you selected for the pulse?

Comment: @DimitarZhekov Vinitial 0, Von 2000, Tdelay 1m, Trise 1p,Ton 5. I made Ton 5 before I shortened the simulation time, so it could be reduced to 2m, but it doesn't matter, I just wanted it to start low, go high after 1 mSec, and then stay high. You'll need to adjust the pulse to mimic whatever you are driving the circuit with. Note that when the input pulse goes low you'll get a negative going pulse from the output.

Comment: Perfect ! 
Thanks